# How can I determine point coordinate sysystem?

Tags: geotools, wgs84

I downloaded GIS data from IPUMS NHGIS. The polygons points are for example:
"[-1967092.8957,1446306.6612]"  I attempted to convert automatically in https://mapshaper.org/ using "-proj wgs84" but it does not work.  What coordinate system is this?

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"zipCode":["98260"],"state":["wa"]},"geometry":{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-1968302.1215,1449300.1059],[-1968298.3137,1449310.9443],[-1968294.8618,1449315.3468],[-1968290.1054,1449330.0428],[-1968290.0382,1449336.5617],[-1968290.4006,1449342.4],[-1968290.0161,1449347.5665],[-1968290.2752,1449357.0465],[-1968290.2867,1449366.5696],[-1968289.6642,1449373.3882],[-1968286.8998,1449380.8548],[-1968281.844,1449397.4154],[-1968279.1963,1449403.6536],[-1968277.3662,1449408.4057],[-1968274.2385,1449413.5892],[-1968272.1117,1449418.8298],[-1968270.4566,1449423.5173],[-1968266.924,1449432.0257],[-1968265.7653,1449438.8054],[-1968264.6157,1449443.6374],[-1968263.7227,1449450.0347],[-1968072.5954,1450072.5991],[-1967986.0856,1450393.5227],[-1967866.0077,1450360.3966],[-1967856.4455,1450393.7876],[-1967731.5014,1450360.9909],[-1967719.8847,1450403.1986],[-1967189.323,1450261.5025],[-1967227.9562,1450112.3353],[-1967196.8433,1450090.9273],[-1967218.7224,1450014.4963],[-1967262.8334,1449860.1289],[-1967234.5887,1449851.9291],[-1967086.8983,1449809.1948],[-1966711.2206,1449700.2984],[-1966631.7749,1450020.8337],[-1966610.6638,1450106.0857],[-1966517.6802,1450073.9717],[-1965922.3556,1449867.9734],[-1965904.225,1449949.9489],[-1965962.0675,1450031.0647],[-1965911.6403,1450283.6283],[-1966125.0492,1450355.8088],[-1966128.1465,1450363.5762],[-1966176.785,1450439.653],[-1966170.9319,1450507.1343],[-1966172.4431,1450508.1407],[-1966181.801,1450514.2586],[-1966187.874,1450523.1071],[-1966191.3631,1450527.3167],[-1966198.3719,1450535.6295],[-1966205.6723,1450546.2054],[-1966208.5263,1450551.2657],[-1966213.2443,1450559.3822],[-1966216.0456,1450564.0829],[-1966217.6194,1450570.6112],[-1966218.6262,1450577.2075],[-1966220.2724,1450587.312],[-1966224.8945,1450598.4979],[-1966226.3051,1450608.8789],[-1966227.1136,1450615.0741],[-1966225.9253,1450629.0699],[-1966225.0915,1450636.6302],[-1966223.1918,1450643.5412],[-1966221.7873,1450650.3646],[-1966222.9735,1450661.255],[-1966222.8843,1450667.3082],[-1966224.7216,1450674.8296],[-1966226.7218,1450682.054],[-1966228.9886,1450688.8953],[-1966231.2278,1450694.4675],[-1966232.6332,1450700.4896],[-1966235.546,1450706.7138],[-1966238.435,1450716.0273],[-1966239.7689,1450722.0279],[-1966240.3907,1450728.0553],[-1966239.2954,1450740.3569],[-1966239.4717,1450749.5826],[-1966239.2495,1450755.8264],[-1966239.5591,1450761.3056],[-1966239.2484,1450766.4923],[-1966235.2423,1450778.3054],[-1966234.0916,1450784.5134],[-1966517.3872,1450852.166],[-1966621.2189,1450876.9511],[-1966599.9821,1450960.4444],[-1966496.6279,1450932.3552],[-1966396.3405,1450905.0306],[-1966381.1752,1450936.7024],[-1966208.5127,1450901.5139],[-1966118.9203,1451264.0866],[-1966393.4688,1451331.072],[-1966879.3959,1451449.6312],[-1966822.988,1451632.4669],[-1966637.7305,1451588.0374],[-1966575.4421,1451778.5929],[-1966761.6602,1451822.3797],[-1966706.9671,1452007.4238],[-1966698.1414,1452039.0738],[-1966235.0033,1451920.8442],[-1965947.3141,1451847.1163],[-1965930.6219,1451903.8099],[-1965673.3202,1452751.0647],[-1965971.4353,1452833.8541],[-1966046.7196,1452854.7126],[-1965820.956,1453570.0278],[-1965806.5007,1453615.8898],[-1966864.0994,1453920.5025],[-1966755.522,1454300.1975],[-1966651.4619,1454279.1142],[-1966616.9419,1454399.3908],[-1966541.0923,1454663.4509],[-1966736.2767,1454719.346],[-1966695.7656,1454858.8913],[-1966895.6512,1454950.7721],[-1966912.3493,1455092.0235],[-1967152.3658,1455157.335],[-1966774.8096,1455720.9731],[-1966767.3582,1455802.6676],[-1966778.8048,1455874.0644],[-1966975.6468,1456423.4476],[-1967012.603,1456536.2122],[-1967011.5512,1456632.9268],[-1967018.2046,1456721.299],[-1967011.9143,1456845.296],[-1967067.6281,1457013.4337],[-1967072.3105,1457062.0216],[-1967064.3817,1457098.9688],[-1967090.5812,1457149.938],[-1967107.1625,1457182.0964],[-1967082.7626,1457230.1488],[-1967081.8105,1457261.2969],[-1967098.8747,1457313.318],[-1967116.4591,1457428.4447],[-1967111.961,1457453.4162],[-1967122.0699,1457529.7046],[-1967122.3352,1457621.5202],[-1967086.6526,1457792.1357],[-1967082.2903,1457853.7267],[-1967115.9906,1457949.9628],[-1967156.2253,1458061.0297],[-1967154.6774,1458131.3396],[-1967142.8169,1458274.7218],[-1967147.5802,1458297.6455],[-1967158.5301,1458349.9781],[-1967145.6574,1458385.6216],[-1967132.3004,1458394.8661],[-1967077.7934,1458389.7946],[-1966922.5777,1458354.6014],[-1966696.9962,1458303.9519],[-1966389.9323,1458249.9183],[-1966257.5349,1458206.8296],[-1966250.8782,1458204.6938],[-1966138.1978,1458151.4321],[-1965835.9473,1457959.7131],[-1965704.5044,1457887.9002],[-1965435.3624,1457774.0249],[-1965413.9912,1457752.3114],[-1965410.231,1457750.4323],[-1965389.3508,1457735.7393],[-1965370.0079,1457711.855],[-1965348.4296,1457699.5996],[-1965324.1595,1457692.651],[-1965287.3021,1457688.1759],[-1965260.7888,1457668.3161],[-1965211.7661,1457660.4732],[-1965148.7877,1457655.5152],[-1965120.1111,1457647.3059],[-1965064.3028,1457638.3242],[-1964988.6347,1457635.9269],[-1964940.0353,1457647.3557],[-1964882.3073,1457649.1774],[-1964841.9615,1457656.8923],[-1964791.5123,1457674.7867],[-1964761.5916,1457691.6775],[-1964724.2184,1457709.7604],[-1964710.4455,1457712.01],[-1964726.8859,1457654.5694],[-1964732.9531,1457612.62],[-1964751.4253,1457568.832],[-1964756.0971,1457531.7577],[-1964753.9109,1457493.5228],[-1964748.0852,1457447.2521],[-1964749.387,1457396.8296],[-1964703.8783,1457289.3236],[-1964703.5414,1457244.6237],[-1964685.3358,1457195.7272],[-1964679.0536,1457151.0457],[-1964661.2604,1457100.4327],[-1964642.5989,1457053.1259],[-1964634.9207,1457013.3194],[-1964610.7083,1456985.4073],[-1964592.5311,1456936.4046],[-1964570.3988,1456880.193],[-1964544.6971,1456815.9661],[-1964539.319,1456763.7464],[-1964530.032,1456729.5569],[-1964518.4095,1456703.528],[-1964503.5345,1456622.2184],[-1964496.6396,1456599.6064],[-1964486.9317,1456567.7042],[-1964472.6939,1456504.9233],[-1964462.2096,1456453.8798],[-1964456.6208,1456406.7597],[-1964461.6003,1456364.498],[-1964471.547,1456329.7345],[-1964452.203,1456268.1296],[-1964441.574,1456213.4901],[-1964387.9465,1456129.9224],[-1964382.6259,1456118.1948],[-1964348.3049,1456043.3621],[-1964310.4577,1455975.6615],[-1964278.7404,1455928.0611],[-1964248.7881,1455899.4265],[-1964213.0598,1455869.9423],[-1964160.2252,1455829.488],[-1964137.6279,1455774.8657],[-1964126.0146,1455738.4062],[-1964125.9561,1455682.3195],[-1964117.1145,1455642.181],[-1964093.4358,1455591.6068],[-1964090.9798,1455583.7955],[-1964076.6123,1455537.8337],[-1964044.9472,1455469.2667],[-1963999.8039,1455381.136],[-1963977.4149,1455325.7714],[-1963952.339,1455280.073],[-1963936.5572,1455268.5649],[-1963902.6899,1455253.6044],[-1963869.7276,1455231.1059],[-1963834.4656,1455221.0214],[-1963786.5926,1455188.0675],[-1963730.0521,1455160.547],[-1963692.7536,1455136.8096],[-1963672.2026,1455116.8295],[-1963663.8961,1455102.4144],[-1963659.4208,1455094.8286],[-1963652.1307,1455074.398],[-1963626.4596,1454984.8451],[-1963508.754,1454624.1743],[-1963499.1455,1454584.5061],[-1963496.4745,1454500.6124],[-1963466.2357,1454314.3552],[-1963448.685,1454242.0308],[-1963421.6102,1454157.352],[-1963414.9081,1454093.2889],[-1963398.4738,1454058.8932],[-1963377.7282,1454018.793],[-1963359.8754,1453927.0046],[-1963342.9257,1453827.677],[-1963329.3297,1453762.5605],[-1963324.6433,1453691.1617],[-1963309.6527,1453630.9211],[-1963291.6925,1453614.4357],[-1963262.958,1453560.701],[-1963228.1932,1453452.8418],[-1963187.6809,1453377.3953],[-1963170.9048,1453285.9151],[-1963159.7358,1453199.7066],[-1963146.9236,1453123.348],[-1963144.4536,1453064.9663],[-1963134.5476,1452986.9158],[-1963125.242,1452952.7237],[-1963112.0484,1452911.3434],[-1963092.8509,1452886.5935],[-1963079.8993,1452844.3651],[-1963058.8231,1452826.1877],[-1963024.4658,1452791.8315],[-1963000.7631,1452741.2565],[-1962950.7015,1452670.1926],[-1962874.8562,1452283.5453],[-1962847.9222,1452222.6456],[-1962796.4099,1452129.2683],[-1962763.1009,1452057.8331],[-1962742.0779,1451996.2148],[-1962715.813,1451937.3417],[-1962688.0302,1451907.0451],[-1962656.1948,1451895.3133],[-1962613.816,1451863.829],[-1962510.6246,1451785.7338],[-1962480.3518,1451768.257],[-1962454.2275,1451753.2274],[-1962439.5155,1451744.7825],[-1962419.5058,1451709.7136],[-1962412.8988,1451698.0795],[-1962363.1379,1451611.3997],[-1962328.2659,1451588.9414],[-1962245.8132,1451532.9427],[-1962233.6231,1451490.476],[-1962217.9221,1451418.6848],[-1962197.8964,1451357.9275],[-1962154.294,1451304.4262],[-1962125.2137,1451248.5366],[-1962062.9485,1451205.0715],[-1962017.6889,1451135.7334],[-1961976.5193,1451067.6783],[-1961952.296,1451005.7237],[-1961917.0332,1450941.0758],[-1961791.7921,1450817.7155],[-1961689.8845,1450778.8752],[-1961602.1258,1450712.6584],[-1961566.452,1450694.907],[-1961381.5392,1450623.3191],[-1961360.3758,1450628.9737],[-1961267.3871,1450593.9474],[-1961222.1463,1450576.5634],[-1961171.2423,1450566.9654],[-1961165.6324,1450560.3192],[-1961136.8326,1450555.1952],[-1961116.8068,1450551.6589],[-1961093.5962,1450545.0347],[-1961049.4,1450520.1532],[-1961012.2682,1450516.5507],[-1960976.982,1450506.4808],[-1960949.2485,1450490.7698],[-1960899.7571,1450484.4435],[-1960872.0236,1450468.7328],[-1960820.4131,1450448.7314],[-1960820.0003,1450429.3512],[-1960801.5239,1450381.1971],[-1960755.3127,1450317.3326],[-1960687.8368,1450240.2927],[-1960614.4141,1450187.9282],[-1960501.7182,1450131.2398],[-1960387.7017,1450079.451],[-1960325.128,1450030.9879],[-1960266.9721,1449988.1425],[-1960257.2224,1449979.2844],[-1960246.3632,1449969.6522],[-1960195.6238,1449924.1073],[-1960170.4961,1449878.4159],[-1960160.5414,1449800.3625],[-1960169.7697,1449726.0607],[-1960174.326,1449664.2994],[-1960173.261,1449655.9697],[-1960166.1766,1449600.7487],[-1960142.6496,1449549.4372],[-1960092.914,1449502.0021],[-1960004.473,1449452.3575],[-1959956.8493,1449414.2398],[-1959878.8896,1449378.0199],[-1959732.1442,1449331.818],[-1959491.3382,1449230.7116],[-1959384.2372,1449162.5715],[-1959356.1419,1449123.1471],[-1959277.8158,1449042.1164],[-1959172.851,1448957.965],[-1959103.6086,1448897.1823],[-1959075.4446,1448872.5306],[-1959061.9976,1448869.5004],[-1958967.7234,1448848.2485],[-1958258.0598,1448688.5605],[-1958201.9061,1448697.0971],[-1958296.5962,1448536.2804],[-1958296.3295,1448519.9243],[-1958300.8059,1448505.0341],[-1958339.0604,1448379.2712],[-1958358.1652,1448341.0328],[-1958363.2422,1448330.8997],[-1958348.2825,1448193.1856],[-1958325.1785,1448119.1895],[-1958383.9867,1448028.0576],[-1958416.9975,1447937.7162],[-1958416.156,1447894.8264],[-1958409.2604,1447872.9127],[-1958400.0664,1447843.6942],[-1958397.9479,1447837.1291],[-1958397.7959,1447819.5441],[-1958379.1428,1447788.6629],[-1958355.9339,1447723.8087],[-1958378.9329,1447647.4679],[-1958409.9751,1447570.8955],[-1958450.3629,1447484.0298],[-1958456.2296,1447473.3541],[-1958485.4441,1447420.1879],[-1958501.6886,1447367.8333],[-1958500.3834,1447322.1737],[-1958483.7975,1447238.4531],[-1958468.6248,1447150.3192],[-1958467.6148,1447144.5283],[-1958470.8233,1447101.4156],[-1958477.9821,1447067.2246],[-1958496.2526,1447034.9375],[-1958506.0326,1447014.3341],[-1958547.1601,1446943.2702],[-1958598.4762,1446886.6886],[-1958643.5847,1446815.3827],[-1958682.0807,1446730.4978],[-1958695.5932,1446679.7711],[-1958723.9315,1446580.2972],[-1958732.7555,1446545.2042],[-1958759.3509,1446477.1078],[-1958763.5658,1446467.5311],[-1958785.8225,1446405.8801],[-1958795.0688,1446370.6776],[-1958816.579,1446232.5668],[-1958840.3472,1446078.015],[-1958841.7779,1446053.7716],[-1958847.5965,1445957.2817],[-1958866.1885,1445870.049],[-1958889.3042,1445814.7184],[-1958895.7905,1445753.5039],[-1958897.1362,1445740.816],[-1958888.986,1445656.2839],[-1958894.6229,1445569.4876],[-1958915.8007,1445495.1442],[-1958919.0333,1445483.7965],[-1958971.0686,1445347.2685],[-1958994.8751,1445263.6977],[-1959017.6242,1445183.8388],[-1959058.4075,1445056.6019],[-1958998.763,1444987.2112],[-1958991.7033,1444885.101],[-1958992.0206,1444816.9678],[-1959000.1336,1444742.3406],[-1959000.4504,1444674.2071],[-1958984.2425,1444575.9115],[-1958927.5833,1444389.1559],[-1958880.7608,1444304.3852],[-1958868.5014,1444282.3187],[-1958832.1373,1444208.8977],[-1958794.2362,1444186.7521],[-1958788.5681,1444139.6171],[-1958757.1638,1444044.1033],[-1958736.5834,1443982.2875],[-1958707.7697,1443903.2209],[-1958687.9359,1443858.0144],[-1958704.3557,1443856.957],[-1958834.2553,1443836.0444],[-1958878.7781,1443780.2699],[-1958954.3703,1443760.7486],[-1958971.8539,1443756.7839],[-1958970.083,1443821.5233],[-1958968.19,1443833.9413],[-1958961.4875,1443876.9807],[-1958950.8072,1443955.694],[-1958950.4797,1443957.6647],[-1958937.8991,1444063.9291],[-1958940.6805,1444117.3517],[-1958956.4731,1444156.1338],[-1958987.5515,1444192.6194],[-1959028.3541,1444226.8296],[-1959051.9188,1444270.4631],[-1959060.2289,1444300.3493],[-1959043.4099,1444394.2836],[-1959023.638,1444457.1055],[-1959021.3935,1444509.211],[-1959054.1759,1444596.2898],[-1959091.922,1444693.9563],[-1959094.7671,1444876.5064],[-1959112.6838,1444905.3453],[-1959167.4984,1444857.6669],[-1959199.3839,1444840.4926],[-1959259.263,1444832.44],[-1959308.2346,1444829.9947],[-1959328.9873,1444833.4991],[-1959423.8047,1444842.0521],[-1959462.233,1444839.8145],[-1959513.184,1444825.2068],[-1959559.3681,1444846.2778],[-1959605.4405,1444830.3952],[-1959753.6384,1444757.6142],[-1959825.3984,1444766.3671],[-1959963.6214,1444805.7575],[-1960078.98,1444812.261],[-1960187.313,1444779.7258],[-1960299.0719,1444703.3329],[-1960546.8227,1444476.2701],[-1960749.3936,1444327.0348],[-1960819.8988,1444300.6925],[-1960928.1734,1444307.939],[-1960963.9008,1444302.3003],[-1961028.9474,1444517.9704],[-1961169.2889,1444955.5613],[-1961243.4186,1445177.7234],[-1961278.5845,1445258.2764],[-1961288.8486,1445282.6476],[-1961667.8225,1445403.5862],[-1961702.452,1445242.1401],[-1962139.3201,1445395.7891],[-1962147.3871,1445373.5499],[-1962171.5415,1445382.9649],[-1962192.2092,1445315.4683],[-1962371.6607,1445386.1698],[-1962386.6278,1445352.3677],[-1962421.7517,1445270.418],[-1962433.456,1445286.7167],[-1962549.925,1445336.8122],[-1962597.6958,1445356.9823],[-1962592.8953,1445374.0757],[-1962557.345,1445501.6601],[-1962549.3484,1445530.2267],[-1962724.8521,1445591.4408],[-1962744.178,1445502.3455],[-1962820.7883,1445234.7572],[-1962846.8297,1445143.7931],[-1962865.6785,1445151.2373],[-1962898.9553,1444979.5373],[-1962859.0819,1444961.8492],[-1962794.8672,1444933.1997],[-1962724.3084,1444901.8239],[-1962819.4487,1444555.5702],[-1962916.3038,1444583.6714],[-1962970.6769,1444618.5717],[-1963157.3586,1444738.6033],[-1963358.6742,1444552.9381],[-1963429.7728,1444345.0085],[-1963767.9522,1444484.1081],[-1963713.075,1444654.9221],[-1963716.0848,1444660.8278],[-1963984.4977,1444735.2938],[-1964291.3156,1444837.2555],[-1964365.371,1444858.8663],[-1964381.6956,1444863.6443],[-1964686.7735,1444952.5119],[-1964735.3853,1444966.7437],[-1964512.7736,1445632.8119],[-1964414.9977,1445925.2057],[-1964387.1542,1446069.7866],[-1964497.0134,1446100.2551],[-1964540.8785,1446112.4435],[-1964771.3843,1446192.8706],[-1964987.6589,1446268.3219],[-1965104.3048,1446308.9983],[-1965587.6164,1446430.9745],[-1965559.4303,1446531.7611],[-1965538.74,1446604.4107],[-1965506.3036,1446720.6121],[-1965922.3458,1446864.5647],[-1966272.8516,1446985.9023],[-1966351.2331,1446760.0012],[-1966537.1023,1446223.9552],[-1966988.0195,1446375.3017],[-1967024.1298,1446444.7034],[-1967051.8269,1446497.8196],[-1967092.8957,1446306.6612],[-1967107.8891,1446282.1604],[-1967149.414,1446286.1259],[-1967188.9124,1446315.7788],[-1967203.8776,1446356.7652],[-1967203.2767,1446377.4692],[-1967227.3834,1446423.7093],[-1967306.1733,1446446.2525],[-1967320.7705,1446479.2196],[-1967329.7437,1446531.5682],[-1967351.1731,1446536.5529],[-1967372.7688,1446866.194],[-1967472.2681,1446863.1234],[-1967615.0142,1446885.6214],[-1967670.9287,1446885.7945],[-1967751.9741,1446919.3134],[-1967770.5882,1446919.3645],[-1967787.9489,1446877.3044],[-1967797.4219,1446872.1012],[-1967874.3049,1446716.4281],[-1967918.6943,1446626.701],[-1968403.292,1446749.2476],[-1968434.4111,1446828.9321],[-1968620.4692,1446806.2664],[-1968622.3685,1446855.6765],[-1968896.8079,1446987.7185],[-1968899.5196,1447024.17],[-1968868.6535,1447227.8881],[-1968761.0859,1447299.2891],[-1968576.0232,1447355.9559],[-1968666.0015,1447392.16],[-1968641.8486,1447473.3541],[-1968611.5095,1447575.3443],[-1968810.0866,1447637.3739],[-1968800.4128,1447671.4251],[-1968751.9383,1447828.1128],[-1968655.1668,1447799.2518],[-1968536.9617,1448179.4905],[-1968433.4611,1448149.2777],[-1968243.312,1448093.6826],[-1968140.7948,1448422.2037],[-1968164.2147,1448433.6124],[-1968240.6983,1448496.1173],[-1968491.8167,1448685.8302],[-1968444.7205,1448845.0861],[-1968321.2566,1449262.8022],[-1968311.4562,1449275.7098],[-1968309.2223,1449280.2315],[-1968304.4425,1449294.4622],[-1968302.1215,1449300.1059]]],[[[-1967173.2728,1458660.9519],[-1967188.653,1458644.3752],[-1967235.0931,1458649.7733],[-1967266.5125,1458679.764],[-1967284.5445,1458719.1048],[-1967273.4581,1458757.7826],[-1967260.7695,1458764.6955],[-1967223.484,1458764.4435],[-1967208.391,1458752.2052],[-1967171.5674,1458676.1732],[-1967173.2728,1458660.9519]]]]}]}}]}
```

Comment: what location does it represent?

Comment: I see by the ZIP code that it's on the west coast of the US. Definitely not in geographic CRS (latitude-longitude). Is there a .prj file with the GIS data download?

Comment: Coordinates in 4326 (WGS84) are in *degrees*, which do not exceed three decimal places. GeoJSON data should be in degrees.

Comment: Go back to the source and read the metadata (a prj file like @mkennedy said would be pertinent metadata). Do not try to quess what it *could be* reshearch *what it is*.

Comment: If you can't find metadata but you can point the location on a map then you may be able to find the coordinate system with this application http://projfinder.com/.

Comment: Please post a link to your data.

Comment: Why would this question get a down vote......

Comment: @mkennedy ah thanks I didn't know I could find that in the .prj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the IPUMS NHGIS website they say:

"We project the data into Esri's USA Contiguous Albers Equal Area Conic Projected Coordinate System"

So that would be ESRI:102003 NAD 1983 Albers contiguous USA.

Center of your Area of Interest would be Latitude,Longitude of 48.027,-122.448.

[image]